# Python - Extract words from quotes from a paragraph without regex

Tags: python, split, strip

I have the following paragraph as Input from a .txt file:

> ... Lorem "ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.". Praesent non sem urna. Pellentesque elementum "turpi'" est, "in fermentum diam auctor aliquam!". Morbi rhoncus erat ipsum, eu "tristique" ...

Here it is as a Python string:

```
'Lorem "ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.". Praesent non sem urna. Pellentesque elementum "turpi" est, "in fermentum diam auctor aliquam!". Morbi rhoncus erat ipsum, eu "tristique"'
```

I want to create a list of only the quoted phrases and isolate the words within the quotes as a list (delimited by white spaces).

Output:

```
['ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet,', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit.', 'turpi'', 'in', 'fermentum', 'diam', 'auctor', 'aliquam!', 'tristique']
```

My thought process has been to read in the file and then somehow split the paragraph by quotes but I cannot seem to find a way to get 'split()' working how I want. I have a feeling this can be done with minimal looping and using split() as a means to organize the data WITHOUT the use of re, shlex, csv or other imported modules.

I even thought about adding the delimiter back into the list and then 'cleaning' the list. But even this feels a bit complicated than it should be.

The code below adds double quotes to every item in the array, which is not what I want. Just a way I felt I could keep track of the quote after using split().

```
with open(input_file, "r") as read_file:
     for line in read_file:
          quotes = ['"' + i + '"' for i in line.split('"') if i]
```

Comment: Did you have a specific question? Apparently you are only trying to tell us that you want to do this task which is cumbersome, but don't want to use the (standard) libraries that would make it easier.

Comment: I mean, you can reinvent the wheel, but why?

Comment: once you split using `"` as a delimiter, can't you simply extract all the odd-indexed elements of the list?  Then split those normally and concatenate the lists together.

Comment: @KevinWang that works! Exactly what I was needing to happen! THANK YOU. That was clever. I'm impressed. How do I give you points? I'm assuming you'd have to write a solution?

Comment: you're welcome, glad I could help :)  I added my suggestion as an Answer, so you can accept/upvote it.

Comment: @Dmtzz consider my answer which implements the logic Kevin described using a one liner list comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copied from my comment:

once you split using " as a delimiter, you can simply extract all the odd-indexed elements of the list. Then, split those normally (with whitespace delimiter) and concatenate the lists together.

Example:

```
text = """Lorem "ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.". Praesent non sem urna. Pellentesque elementum "turpi'" est, "in fermentum diam auctor aliquam!". Morbi rhoncus erat ipsum, eu "tristique" """

text_split_by_quotes = text.split('"')
# get the odd-indexed elements (here's one way to do it):
text_in_quotes = text_split_by_quotes[1::2]
# split each normally (by whitespace) and flatten the list (here's one way to do it):
ans = []
for text in text_in_quotes:
    ans.extend(text.split())
# print answer
print(ans)

>>> ['ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet,', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit.', "turpi'", 'in', 'fermentum', 'diam', 'auctor', 'aliquam!', 'tristique']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible approaches:

```
desired = [
    'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet,', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit.',
    'turpi\'', 'in', 'fermentum', 'diam', 'auctor', 'aliquam!', 'tristique'
    ]

text = """
Lorem "ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.". Praesent non sem
urna. Pellentesque elementum "turpi'" est, "in fermentum diam auctor aliquam!".
Morbi rhoncus erat ipsum, eu "tristique"
"""

def extract_quoted(text):
    words = []
    next_pos = -1
    while True:
        try:
            pos = text.index('"', next_pos + 1)
        except ValueError:
            break
        try:
            next_pos = text.index('"', pos + 1)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise ValueError("mismatched quotes") from e
        quoted_segment = text[pos + 1:next_pos]
        words.extend(quoted_segment.split())
    return words

def split_only(text):
    return [word for chunk in text.split('"')[1::2] for word in chunk.split()]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(extract_quoted(text) == desired)
    print(split_only(text) == desired)
```

The first is a little more explicit about how the text is sort of being
"parsed", while the second is probably more the flashy one-line splitting based
approach you're looking for.

Comment: I do enjoy your 1 liner, although my python knowledge is fair, it has the same feel of logic @KevinWang shared which adds to my understanding of the list comprehension.

I appreciate the time you took write this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
a = """Lorem "ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.". Praesent non sem urna. Pellentesque elementum "turpi'" est, "in fermentum diam auctor aliquam!". Morbi rhoncus erat ipsum, eu "tristique" """
in_quote = 0
res = []
word = ''

for i in a:
    if i == '"':
        in_quote = 1 - in_quote
        if word:
            res+=[word]
            word = ''
    elif in_quote:
        if i == ' ':
            res+=[word]
            word = ''
        else:
            word+=i
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this logic, essentially after splitting you can simply select every second index since you start without double quotes in your text.

```
text = 'Lorem "ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.". Praesent non sem urna. Pellentesque elementum "turpi" est, "in fermentum diam auctor aliquam!". Morbi rhoncus erat ipsum, eu "tristique"'
print(text)

split_text = text.split('"')
print(split_text)

new_split_text = [elem for i,elem in enumerate(split_text) if i%2 == 1]
print(new_split_text)
```

**if you want a one liner:**

```
new_split_text = [elem for i,elem in enumerate(text.split('"')) if i%2 == 1]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'turpi', 'in fermentum diam auctor aliquam!', 'tristique']
```

Comment: Downvotes without comments? Is my attempt to help really that bad? If so, just let me know why so I can improve next time.